# Error with setup:di:compile M 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3

I upgrade yesterday to Magento 2.3.3 from 2.3.2, which seemed to go relatively smoothly.

I tried to do a setup:di:compile today and got this error

```
In PhpScanner.php line 177:

  Class \My\NamespaceA\My\NamespaceB\InterfaceB does not exist
```

I've tried googling, but this error doesn't seem to be reported.  This class seems generic enough that I can't track it down.  Has anyone seen this before, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a \ missing at the start on a use or other class type declaration. That means magento thinks the module you're referring to should be located in the one that you're calling it from. It should be \Vendor\Module...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is your problem

You should to remove folder generated,vendor and recompile

```
sudo rm -rf generated

sudo rm -rf vendor

composer install

php bin/magento set:di:com
```